# FileSystemWatcher resetting EnableRaisingEvents after invocation

Tags: c#, file-watcher

I need to process a number of directories and process files as they are created or renamed. To do this I created the following Watcher Class.

```
public class Watcher
{
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = null;

    public delegate void FileCreatedEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);
    public delegate void FileRenamedEventHandler(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e);
    public delegate void LogEventHandler(object sender, String e);

    public event FileCreatedEventHandler FileCreated;
    public event FileRenamedEventHandler FileRenamed;
    public event LogEventHandler LogEvent;


    public String Directory { get; set; }
    public String DAP { get; set; }
    public String Filter { get; set; }
    public Watcher()
    {
        fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    }

    public Watcher(String directory, String filter, String dap)
    {
        this.DAP            = dap;
        this.Directory      = directory;
        this.Filter         = filter;
    }

    public void StartWatch()
    {
        if (fileSystemWatcher == null) fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Filter = Filter;
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = Directory;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;

        Log(String.Format("Watching Directory {0}", Directory));
    }

    private void FileSystemWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileRenamed?.Invoke(sender, e);

    }

    private void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    { 
        FileCreated?.Invoke(sender, e);            
    }

    private void Log ( String Message )
    {
        LogEvent?.Invoke(this, Message);
    }

}
```

That in turn is used by the following function, which sets up a number of instances; one for each of the directories being watched.

```
    public ProfileWatcher()
    {
        List<nhs_acquisition_profile> p = null;
        List <Watcher> fwList = new List<Watcher>();

        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("DirectoryScanner"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "DirectoryScanner","ProfileDirectoryScanner");
            }

            // 
            profileWatcherLog.Source = "DirectoryScanner";
            profileWatcherLog.Log = "ProfileDirectoryScanner";

            using (nhs_acquisition_profiles profiles = new nhs_acquisition_profiles(Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnection))
            {
                profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("retrieving list of DAP Profiles");

                p = profiles.Select<nhs_acquisition_profile>(null);

                profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Found {0} Directories to watch.", p.Count.ToString()));

                foreach (nhs_acquisition_profile pfl in p)
                {
                    Watcher w = null;

                    try
                    {

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Attempting to set-up watcher on {0} for DAP {1}",pfl.dap_file_location,pfl.dap_name));
                        w = new Watcher(pfl.dap_file_location, "*.*", pfl.dap_name);

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Initialising Event Handlers");
                        // initialise event handlers
                        w.FileCreated   += W_FileCreated;
                        w.FileRenamed   += W_FileRenamed;
                        w.LogEvent      += W_LogEvent;
                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Event Handlers initialised");

                        w.StartWatch();

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Watch started....Adding to Watcher List");

                        // add the watcher to the list of watchers
                        fwList.Add(w);

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Added to list of file watchers");

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Watching {0} for files matching *.* for DAP {1}",pfl.dap_file_location,pfl.dap_name));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("ERROR: {0}",e.Message),EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Profile Watcher setup");
        }

    }
```

Each time a file is created it should call one of the following

```
    private void W_FileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("File Renamed From {0} to {1}", e.OldName, e.Name));

            using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = ((System.IO.FileSystemWatcher)sender))
            {
                if (watcher != null)
                    Process(watcher.Path);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    private void W_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("File Created {0}", e.Name));

            using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = ((System.IO.FileSystemWatcher)sender))
            {
                if (watcher != null)
                    Process(watcher.Path);
            }
        }
        catch ( System.Exception ex)
        {
            profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);   
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
```

This is fine for the first time a file is dropped into a target directory. The trouble is it is resetting the EnableRaisingEvents once it returns from the

```
FileCreated?.Invoke(sender, e);
```

Line in the first listing above.

Nothing in the code seems to be doing this and when I try and reset it back after the FileCreated it then moans that the object has been disposed (even though the debugger shows it has a value)

The whole thing is then wrapped in a service, so that it runs all the time.

Comment: Why does `fileSystemWatcher` only get instantiated from one of the constructors and not the other?

Comment: I only access it directly in the first class, the second class it is passed in the event handler and is already instantiated.

Comment: It happens when FSW raises its Error event.  A very important event you never want to ignore.

Comment: Hans Passant - Tried creating an event handler for FileSystemWatcher_Error and that did not get called.

Comment: What’s the point of the `using` blocks? That seems like it would be calling `Dispose` On the FSW instance prematurely.